# Htaccess Redirect Match 301 Preserve links and files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have moved to a new domain name and I tried many codes to make a redirect match 301 to all links and files on the old website. So basically I would like a code that does this:

```
http://oldsite.com/subfolder/*.jpg/html/js/etc. to http://newsite.com/subfolder/*.jpg/html/js/etc.

http://oldsite.com/subfolder2/*.jpg/html/js/etc. to http://newsite.com/subfolder2/*.jpg/html/js/etc.

http://oldsite.com/*.jpg/html/js/etc. to http://newsite.com/*.jpg/html/js/etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

**In folder: /subfolder/ make a .htaccess file and paste this code:**

> RedirectMatch permanent ^/subfolder/(.*)$
>   http://newsite.com/subfolder/$1

**In folder: /subfolder2/ make a .htaccess file and paste this code:**

> RedirectMatch permanent ^/subfolder2/(.*)$
>   http://newsite.com/subfolder2/$1

**In the root folder of the old website make a .htaccess file and paste this code:**

> RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1